# php - check all records from DB

Tags: php

I create a function to check and delete favorites. This function checks if the ads not exists. If not, they delete all.

There is no errors, but is not working...

```
  //delete liked favorites that the ads are invalid

   $check_favorites = "SELECT favorite_id, ads_id FROM public_favorites";
   $check_favorites_qry = $con->query($check_favorites);   

while($checked = $check_favorites_qry->fetch_assoc()) {

      $invalid_ads = "SELECT ads_id FROM public_ads WHERE ads_id = '". $checked['ads_id'] ."'";
      $invalid_ads_qry = $con->query($invalid_ads);

      if($invalid_ads_qry->num_rows < 1) {

          while($unavailable = $invalid_ads_qry->fetch_assoc()) {

              $update_dates = "DELETE FROM public_favorites WHERE favorite_id = '". $checked['favorite_id'] ."'";
              $query_updated = $con->query($update_dates);                 

          }
      }        
}
```

Where am i wrong?

Comment: hint: try debugging your code. either place breakpoints on each line or echo out on each line to see what it contains/returns

Comment: If there are no errors than it must be working :p

Comment: Also FYI, you are not echoing anything. The above should actually give you a blank page

Comment: okok i changed the "query" to $check_favorites_qry.

Comment: Its working, but.. is not deleting all, deletes 1 by 1 and in the final left 1.

Comment: why don't you just use a `JOIN`? isn't there a relationship between the tables `public_ads` and `public_favorites`?

Comment: @Akintunde007 yes, there is about the ads_id... But i never used JOIn, can you help me to fix it?

Comment: @Akintunde007 i created. but now i need to check if the ADS exists in the public_ads ... then delete the favorite_id... How can i do it?